# Why don't we create an entire GUI in the main() method of an object?

Tags: java, class, user-interface, methods, program-entry-point

Is it we can only add existing components (no custom components) to a GUI that is implemented using main()? or is it absolutely necessary to create GUI's in a custom class.

Comment: We need objects for multiple reasons, but not having to repeat code over and over again is my first reason I can think of

Comment: Another way to look at it: you can either go to the store and buy all the objects you need for your kitchen, or you can make them from scratch yourself. Which is easier?

Comment: There's no absolute necessity for anything. You can code a complete and complex GUI using assembly language, no methods, no classes, and with spaghetti code and goto statements, but as the program scales up, complexity and bug risk scales higher geometrically. You use classes here the same reason you use good OOPs techniques for any program -- to help reduce complexity and thus reduce risk of bugs.

Comment: Voting to close for being too broad as this is nothing more than a specialized version of "why use OOPs?"

Answer (score 4):

You can structure the code like you want. You can of course implement a whole GUI inside a **main method**. Theoretically you can always transform any code such that it only uses **one** *main method* and nothing more.

Java is an **object oriented language**. We want to structure our code such that it is **easy to read, understand, maintain** and **reusable** without **duplicating code**. That means we use a `Button` class and a `Panel` class and put that together instead of just writing everything from top to down inside one *main method*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is for the same reason you would implement classes outside of main in any other Java program.

If you throw everything into the main method, you lose the ability to reuse the code you wrote.

If you put functionality into different methods, fields, and classes, then you have a chance at better design and re usability within your code.

Comment: so just to make it reusable?

Comment: that's not the only reason but one of the core pillars, if you will, of object oriented programming